# TypeError raised when using concurrent.futures

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I am trying to use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor to optimize some exiting code, but the program actually goes wrong.

```
def main():
dataDB = DataStorage.DataStorage("127.0.0.1", 27017)

data_catch_info = {}
data_catch_info["tempName"] = "catch_data_demo"
data_catch_info["lgURL"] = []
data_catch_info["author"] = "corporate slave"

url_pool = LookingURLPool.LgPool()

thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

with DataProducer.DataProducer() as dp:
    tasks = []
    for url in url_pool.lg_pool("template1"):
        # thread_func(url,url_pool,dataDB,dp,data_catch_info)
        tasks.append(thread_pool.submit(thread_func,(url,url_pool,dataDB,dp,data_catch_info)))
    print(wait(tasks))

del thread_pool
del url_pool
del dataDB
```

It finally print:

DoneAndNotDoneFutures(done={<Future at 0x1978ae6e040 state=finished raised TypeError>, <Future at 0x1978aeb8d90 state=finished raised TypeError>, ...<Future at 0x1978ae79fd0 state=finished raised TypeError>, <Future at 0x1978aeceb50 state=finished raised TypeError>}, not_done=set())

Can anyone explain what's going wrong?

Comment: What does your *wait()* function do?

Comment: It's imported from concurrent.futures.

Answer (score 0):

Now everything is OK!

Just change`tasks.append(thread_pool.submit(thread_func,(url,url_pool,dataDB,dp,data_catch_info)))` as `tasks.append(thread_pool.submit(thread_func,(url),(url_pool),(dataDB),(dp),(data_catch_info)))`

When submit a func requiring not only params, we are expected to divide params into different ().